# Mysql select values from array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, select

I have the following array created:

```
$selectedvillas[] = array (
    'villaname' => $row1['name']
```

and with

```
print_r($selectedvillas);
```

It prints:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [villaname] => Villa 1 ) [1] => Array ( [villaname] => Villa 2 ) [2] => Array ( [villaname] => Villa 3 ) [3] => Array ( [villaname] => Villa 4 ) [4] => Array ( [villaname] => Villa 5 ) [5] => Array ( [villaname] => Villa 6 ) [6] => Array ( [villaname] => Villa 7 ) [7] => Array ( [villaname] => Villa 8 ) [8] => Array ( [villaname] => Villa 9 ) [9] => Array ( [villaname] => Villa 10 ) [10] => Array ( [villaname] => Villa 11 ) [11] => Array ( [villaname] => Villa 12 ) )
```

I want to select from mysql all the above villaname from the array where villa is the above array with the villanames

```
$query_reviews= "SELECT * FROM reviews where villa IN $selectedvillas order by dateofreview DESC";
```

Comment: You have to use PHP explode function to build a string "$list = explode(',',$selectedvillas);"

After:
$query_reviews= "SELECT * FROM reviews where villa IN ($list) order by dateofreview DESC";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to format your array into a string.

First off, it seems like you could make your job easier by building up your array more simply, like so:

`$selectedvillas[] = $row1['name'];`

Then you can use `implode()` to easily format your array in a comma separated string.

I use this quite often:

```
$query_reviews= "SELECT * FROM reviews 
WHERE villa IN ('" .implode("', '", $selectedvillas) . "') order by dateofreview DESC";
```

Note: Those single quotes are easy to miss but they are important.